# I did whatever I could but Facebook is NOT clearing website cache

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I searched and followed whatever stackoverflow answers suggested to get that latest website cache on Facebook.
After following multiple answers, this is my fat `head`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Lively Roof</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="2299258843720626">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="682">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1024">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.livelyroof.com">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="The easy, safe way to rent a room, where housemates can exchange help around the house for lower rent">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Lively Roof">
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.livelyroof.com/assets/img/main.png"> <!-- also tried og:image instead of og:image:url but no effect -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:description" content="The easy, safe way to rent a room, where housemates can exchange help around the house for lower rent">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="assets/img/main.png">
    <meta name="description" content="The easy, safe way to rent a room, starting with one month, where housemates can exchange help around the house for lower rent">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
```

**What I tried To Clear Cache:**
1) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ with url: https://www.livelyroof.com

2) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livelyroof.com

> 1) and 2) Result: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. The
>   following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title,
>   og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

---

3)https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ with https://www.livelyroof.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING

4) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livelyroof.com%3Ffbrefresh%3DCAN_BE_ANYTHING

> 3) and 4) Result: Object at URL
>   'https://www.livelyroof.com/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING' of type
>   'website' is invalid because the given value 'assets/img/1.png' for
>   property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

---

Now, when I try to share url on FB, random image from website is shown as website preview instead of omg:image:url

Answer (score 0):

Patient is the key, not those cache clearing fb debuggers (36 hours to be exact). FB debugger is still showing some issues with the metatags but I can now see the latest image preview of website when sharing link on fb.

P.S: I also set-up the fb pixel during the waiting time not sure if that helped or not.